# What are the fan dimensions for EATON 5E 2000I USB UPS 2000VA/1200W

Tags: fan, ups

I would like to replace the fan because it's too noisy but I'm not sure what the dimensions are. It looks like a 50mm fan and I'm trying to find an accurate datasheet for the UPS or a service manual to verify the correct dimensions but I can't.

If anyone has opened this UPS before and can provide some info I'd be grateful.

Comment: Looking at one of these online I can see that this is bolted to the back of the case.  Why not just measure the distance between the centers of the screw and then "reverse engineer" the measurement to an appropriate sized fan?  The datasheet does not help much ere, but it can be found at https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/backup-power-ups-surge-it-power-distribution/backup-power-ups/eaton_5e_ups/Eaton%205E%20UPS%20-%20%20Datasheet.pdf

Comment: It looks like a 60mm one but I'm not sure about how thick it can be. Like 25mm or 26mm? etc etc. I saw the datasheet as well but I guess I need a service manual for this or to get the fan's part number :(